# How to redirect to Branch maintenance

Tags: acumatica

I have a BQL which selects Branch.BAccountID, for a particular branch.  Next I use the Search method, with a type BranchMaint graph.  When I throw the PXRedirection exception, the system opens the Branch maintenance screen.  Unfortunately the screen does not navigate to a branch record.  The screen behaves like it expects to enter a new branch record.  Using debug, I noticed graph.BAccount.Current equals NULL.  Strange that the Search method does not locate the correct Branch record

```
    BranchMaint graph = new BranchMaint();
        Branch b = PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Required<Branch.branchID>>>>.Select(this, this.Assessment.Current.ReceiveBranchID);            
        if (b!=null)
        {
            graph.BAccount.Current = graph.BAccount.Search<Branch.branchID>(b.BranchID);
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, "Redirect");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer...

```
    Branch branch = PXSelect<Branch, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Required<Branch.branchID>>>>.Select(this, this.Assessment.Current.ReceiveBranchID);

    BranchMaint.BranchBAccount branchRow = PXSelect<BranchMaint.BranchBAccount,
                            Where<PX.Objects.CS.BranchMaint.BranchBAccount.branchBranchCD,
                                  Equal<Required<PX.Objects.CS.BranchMaint.BranchBAccount.branchBranchCD>>>>.Select(graph, branch.BranchCD);
```